# How to detect Xbox controller key press events in Windows 11 in Winjs UWP app?

Tags: javascript, uwp, winjs, gamepad, windows-11

I am not able to navigate in my UWP WinJS app using a gamepad controller in Windows 11. It is working fine in Windows 10 though.

I also found out that I am no longer getting keydown event when pressing any key on Xbox controller.

I am confused. Anyone can advise something to try. TIA
I've also created a sample app, which just prints the key captured by keydown event. Works fine in Windows 10 but not in Windows 11.
Sample App:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj082Ju6Hyp0jo4mPd9nq6vO3zStzA?e=qplpBs

Ref:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.virtualkey?view=winrt-20348

Comment: Does the key down event work for a keyboard on Windows11 in your app?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT: yes, it works for keyboard.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT: Here is a sample.  This sample works fine in Windows 10, can detect gamepad controller events but Windows 11 can only detect keyboard events. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj082Ju6Hyp0jo4mPd9nq6vO3zStzA?e=qplpBs

Comment: I'll try to find someone to test and check out this. Please submit feedback in the Feedback Hub app about this as well. You could find the Feedback hub app in the Star Menu.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT: I really appreciate that. I've submitted feedback in the Feedback Hub app. Here is the link: https://aka.ms/AAdswjc

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT did you get chance to try this? Thanks.

Comment: Well, since Windows 11 is not officially released, please submit your issue in the Feedback Hub. It's the best channel to report this.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT: yes, already did that. Hoping MS look into that and comment or acknowledge :)

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I have a similar issue in that I am not getting any keypress/keydown events from the controller on Windows 11, but inside a Webview running on a C#/XAML UWP app. I have not tested if it works as expected on Windows 10, but I suspect it might. Since Windows 11 is officially released, I think this question deserves a second look. Here is the question I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975642/webview-not-receiving-input-from-xbox-controller-on-windows-11